# Toggle button to change properties of something outside its class - Kivy

Tags: python, user-interface, properties, binding, kivy

So I'm having trouble understanding how to change the colour of a button that's on a different screen to the button that changes that buttons colour (sorry if this is hard to understand). I'm fairly new to python and really new to Kivy so I'll try and explain this as best I can.

In the `<ChannelOneWindow>` I've got the enableSwitchOne ToggleButton changing the colour of itself and colourMarkerOne through an if statement. I also need enableSwitchOne to change the colour of colourMarker1 in the `<HomeWindow>`. I understand that this is probably done by binding, but the Kivy framework isn't well documented and I'm having a real hard time with this. Can anyone help?

.kv File -

```
#: import sm kivy.uix.screenmanager

WindowManager:
    HomeWindow:
    ChannelOneWindow:



<HomeWindow>:
    name: "home"

    FloatLayout:


        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.0,"y":0.70}
            size_hint: 1.0, 0.2
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 12**4
            background_normal: '0'
            id: armSwitch
            text: "SAFE"
            background_color: 0, 1, 0, 1
            on_press:
                root.updateText()
                root.updateColour()
                print("Sending To FPGA")




        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0,"y":0}
            size_hint: 0.16, 0.17
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4 #14**4
            text: "1"   
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.channeloneBtn()





        ToggleButton:
            pos_hint:{"x":0,"y":0.17}
            size_hint: 0.16, 0.05
            id: colourMarker1
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4
            background_color: 5, 0, 0, 1            


<ChannelOneWindow>:
    name: "channelone"

    FloatLayout:

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.0,"y":0.90}
            size_hint: 0.20, 0.09
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 15**4
            text: "Home"
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right" 
                root.homeBtn()  

        TextInput:
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 15**4
            multiline: False
            pos_hint: {"x":0.20, "y":0.91}
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.08                    


        ToggleButton:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.35,"y":0.30}
            size_hint: 0.30, 0.10
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4
            background_normal: '0'
            id: enableSwitchOne
            text: "DISABLED"
            background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
            on_state: 
                root.Enabled(*args)


        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0,"y":0}
            size_hint: 0.16, 0.17
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4 #14**4
            text: "1"   





        ToggleButton:
            pos_hint:{"x":0,"y":0.17}
            size_hint: 0.16, 0.05
            background_normal: '0'
            id: colourMarkerOne
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4
            background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
            on_state: 
                root.Enabled(*args)



'''''''
```

.py File -

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label



class HomeWindow (Screen):
    name = ObjectProperty(None)
    c = NumericProperty(0)


    def updateText(self):
        self.ids.armSwitch.text="ARMED"
    def updateColour(self):
        self.ids.armSwitch.background_color= 1, 0, 0, 1

    def channeloneBtn(self):
        self.reset()
        sm.current = "channelone"



    def reset(self):
          pass


class ChannelOneWindow (Screen):
    name = ObjectProperty(None)
    c = NumericProperty(0)




    def Enabled(self, *args):
        if args[1]=='down':
            self.Status = "Device on"
            self.ids.enableSwitchOne.background_color= 0, 1, 0, 1
            self.ids.colourMarkerOne.background_color= 0, 1, 0, 1
            self.ids.enableSwitchOne.text="ENABLED"

            print("Channel 1 Enabled")
            c = 1
        else:
            self.Status = "Device off"
            self.ids.enableSwitchOne.background_color= 1, 0, 0, 1
            self.ids.colourMarkerOne.background_color= 1, 0, 0, 1
            self.ids.enableSwitchOne.text="DISABLED"
            print("Channel 1 Disabled")
            c = 0


    def homeBtn(self):
        self.reset()
        sm.current = "home"



    def reset(self):
        pass



class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass



kv = Builder.load_file("buzzcut.kv")

sm = WindowManager()


screens = [HomeWindow(name="home"),ChannelOneWindow(name="channelone") ]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)


    sm.current = "home"

class BuzzcutApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    BuzzcutApp().run()
```

''''''

Let me know if more information is needed and I'll do my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `self.manager.get_screen("home")`

```
self.manager.get_screen("home").ids.colourMarker1.background_color
```

## [Kivy ScreenManager » get_screen](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager.get_screen)

> ```
> get_screen(name)
> ```
>
> Return the screen widget associated with the name or raise a
>   ScreenManagerException if not found.

## Snippets

```
class ChannelOneWindow(Screen):
    name = ObjectProperty(None)
    c = NumericProperty(0)

    def Enabled(self, *args):
        if args[1] == 'down':
            self.Status = "Device on"
            self.ids.enableSwitchOne.background_color = 0, 1, 0, 1
            self.ids.colourMarkerOne.background_color = 0, 1, 0, 1
            self.ids.enableSwitchOne.text = "ENABLED"
            self.manager.get_screen("home").ids.colourMarker1.background_color = 0, 1, 0, 1

            print("Channel 1 Enabled")
            c = 1
        else:
            self.Status = "Device off"
            self.ids.enableSwitchOne.background_color = 1, 0, 0, 1
            self.ids.colourMarkerOne.background_color = 1, 0, 0, 1
            self.ids.enableSwitchOne.text = "DISABLED"
            self.manager.get_screen("home").ids.colourMarker1.background_color = 1, 0, 0, 1
            print("Channel 1 Disabled")
            c = 0
```

Comment: That's great, thank you so much. Now to implement this a load more time through the app. Thanks again